# Reference series by time - What was the value X days ago?

Tags: pine-script

To reference a value stored in a series with Tradingview's PineScript you use an subscript integer to call a value from a series.

```
//What's the UNIX time of the previous bar?

time[1]

//What's the UNIX time of the 21st bar (counting from current time)

time[20]
```

My goal is to map an input of number of calendar days to a subscript integer to call the value of a series, such that it returns the value of that series, x days ago

```
Pseudo code:
SeriesIndexedByDays([series],[day,integer],[period]):

SeriesIndexedByDays(close,30):
Return close[30*Bars_per_day]
//Returns close value 30 days ago
```

The closest I've been able to achieve with PineScript is:

```
//Method 1:
days = input(title="Reference Point, # of Days", type=integer, defval=1, minval=0.01)
bars_per_day = 24*60/interval // 24 Hours per day * 60 Minutes per hour / [X (Minutes||Days||Weeks||Months||Years)] per bar
number_of_bars_reference_point = bars_per_day*days // Bars per day * Days
close[number_of_bars_reference_point]
```

But this isn't ideal because PineScript's [interval](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_interval) is the prefix multiple of whatever [period](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#var_period) the bar is: [10m, 5m, 5D] -> [10, 5, 5]
So if you change the period from 5 minutes to 5 days interval still outputs the same value: 5

The second attempt I made was:

```
//Method 2:
sec_per_day=24*60*60 // 24 hours per day * 60 minutes per hour * 60 seconds per minute = Seconds per day
t = time //Dump UNIX time into a variable
deltat=t-t[1] //Difference of UNIX time between this and previous bar, not necessarily the time of one bar (ex. session close, exchange's clock jumps due to offline or non continuous bars)
seconds_per_bar=lowest(deltat,2)/1000 // Use the lowest of the last two deltat values in case bar is the start of a session, divide by 1000convert from milliseconds to seconds
bars_per_day = sec_per_day/seconds_per_bar //Series, number of bars per day //Occationally this produces abberant values, assumption is that its because time dates 
retrospective_reference_point_number_of_bars=bars_per_day*days
```

This produces retrospective_reference_point_number_of_bars as a series which correctly maps [days,period]->[bars].  But when used to call another series

```
close[retrospective_reference_point_number_of_bars]
```

TradingView returns an error:

```
out of depth at index
```

Other problems with Method 2 include, if period is less than the 'days' input, then it'll return a value with decimals/float which cannot be used to reference a series.

**Possible Methods**
If I could convert the first value of the output series of Method 2 to an integer, I could use that.

What ideas do you have for solving the mapping of [period,interval,days]->[bars]?

Comment: There's a lot going on in this question, with all kinds of errors (and you haven't even included them all). So you definitely got a hard time with this script! The only thing I can suggest is to first fix [TradingView's out of depth at index error](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/out-of-depth-index/). Then take it from there, and tackle each of the different issues. If you could update your question with a focused problem (instead of multiple that intertwine with each other) that would be great! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix TradingView out of depth at index 540 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912703/how-to-fix-tradingview-out-of-depth-at-index-540-error)

Comment: I'm trying a similar thing, which is to "get the price exactly 1 year ago". I feel like I should be able to use the `valuewhen()` function, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.