# Pine scripting: how to find the price X days ago

Tags: date, time, pine-script

In Pine Script, how do I find the price based on a certain number of days ago? I've tried something like this...

```
// Find the price 90 days ago
target = time - 90 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000
valuewhen(time < target, close, 1)
```

...however `time < target` never seems to return true – presumably because the current bar's time cannot also be in the past at the same time. Perhaps `valuewhen()` wasn't designed to be used with dynamic values that change on every bar?

Do I need to use a loop instead, and scan through every past bar until I find the date I'm looking for?

Comment: Some similar (but not exact) questions asked previously: [Reference series by time - What was the value X days ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261646/reference-series-by-time-what-was-the-value-x-days-ago), [How to get bar index on specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63025721/how-to-get-bar-index-on-specific-date)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a better way, but the workaround I'm using currently using is a function with a `for` loop, scanning backwards until the appropriate date is found. Here is my function:

```
priceXDaysAgo(numDays) =>
    targetTimestamp = time - numDays*60*60*24*1000
    
    // Declare a result variable with a "void" value
    float result = if false
        1
        
    // We'll scan backwards through the preceding bars to find the first bar
    // earlier than X days ago (it might be a little greater than X days if
    // there was a break in trading: weekend, public holiday, etc.)
    for i = 1 to 1000
        if time[i] < targetTimestamp
            result := close[i]
            break
    result
```

You can then call the function anywhere in your script:

```
priceXDaysAgo(90)
```